# Background slideshow with CSS (fullscreen+responsive)

Tags: css, background, slideshow

Is there an easy way, using only CSS, to enable background image slideshow?
I have the background image defined as fullscreen and responsive inside the html property in CSS and would like it to have a simple transition effect. The CSS looks like this:

```css
html {
 background: url(slike/bg.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Do I need to define it in html and make a new CSS class? The only 'problem' is that the backgrounds need to be fullscreen and responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by using the container div like this

```css
html,body {

  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
body {
 margin: 0;
}
.container 
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#slideshow {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.elemnt,.elemnt1,.elemnt2,.elemnt3 {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}
span{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 hsla(0,0%,30%, .3);
  font-size:4em;
  background-color:#fff
}
.elemnt {
  animation: xfade 16s 8s infinite;
  background-image: url('http://desert-maroc.com/wordpress2012/wp-content/uploads/trek-sahara-sauvage-min.jpg');
}
.elemnt1 {
  animation: xfade 16s 6s infinite;
  background-image: url('http://desert-maroc.com/wordpress2012/wp-content/uploads/sahara-desert-by-ellie-1024x683.jpg');
  
}
.elemnt2 {
  animation: xfade 16s 2s infinite;
  background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C4JYsjcWYAAixfx.jpg');
}
.elemnt3 {
  animation: xfade 16s 0s infinite;
  background-image: url('http://desert-maroc.com/wordpress2012/wp-content/uploads/trek-sahara-sauvage-min.jpg');
  
}
@keyframes xfade{
  17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}
@keyframes xfade1{
  17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}
@keyframes xfade2{
  17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}
@keyframes xfade3{
  17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div id="slideshow">
  <div class="elemnt"><span>Text Slider 1</span></div>
  <div class="elemnt1"><span>Text Slider 2</span></div>
  <div class="elemnt2"><span>Text Slider 3</span></div>
  <div class="elemnt3"><span>Text Slider 4</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this now the slider is using only css you can modify the timing, by changing the animation duration

Comment: The slideshow CSS code goes inside the html tagged "container"?

Comment: Can you share the html of the slide show, so i can put it in the right place

Comment: <div class="crossfade">
 <figure></figure>
 <figure></figure>
 <figure></figure>
 <figure></figure>
 <figure></figure>
 <figure></figure>
 <figure></figure>
</div> , However, I don't have a CSS code for the slideshow that works as I want it to work (transitions are too quick, etc), and was based on another approach

Comment: is this what, you asked for !?

Comment: Only one image source is defined?

Comment: i what image source !?

Comment: you can take off the margin-top

Comment: Not good. It's not fullscreen (top left corner has black border now) and image stretches out of the browser screen (scroll bars appear). Some images are staying longer (not consistent animation). Also I lost my JS navigation menu now.

Comment: and as i told you you can modify the animation by changing the duration time

Comment: Same problems, only the border (because of body background) is white now. Background image is still offset. Also I forgot to mention, I don't need text on each image (the span), thanks for considering.

Comment: i corrected that to, you just needed to add margin:0 to the body, because the browser give the body a margin of 8px.

Comment: Previously, I used this example: http://www.cssscript.com/css-only-crossfading-background-slideshow/ and it worked, only the timing of images was bad because the slideshow was too quick (a lot of time spent on transitions and only one second showing the image)

Comment: `.crossfade > figure:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
  background-image: url('2.jpg');
}

.crossfade > figure:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 24s;
  background-image: url('3.jpg');
}

.crossfade > figure:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 36s;
  background-image: url('4.jpg');
}

.crossfade > figure:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 56s;
  background-image: url('5.jpg');
}` try this css

Comment: i doubled the duration time of the animation

Comment: And could you, mark the this question as answered, to help the community.

Comment: The loop is inconsistent and goes blank at the end of the series.